# delay without freezing multimedia

Tags: qt

so i want it to play a video for certain time, so right after `play();`  i use the function `delay();`:
but it freezes the stream so i only get the audio , no image.???
and i can't use the timer.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
    QBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(videoWidget);
    ui->centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
    p.setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
    filename=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"select movie","/");
    this->setWindowTitle(filename);
    p.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename));
    p.setPosition(300000);
    p.play();

    delay(4000);
    p.setPosition(p.position()+1800000);
    delay(4000);
    p.setPosition(p.position()+1800000);
    delay(4000);
}
void MainWindow:: delay( int millisecondsToWait )
{
    QEventLoop loop;
     QTimer::singleShot( millisecondsToWait, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
     loop.exec();
}
```

without delay it will run the video normally but i want it to play only 4 sec each 30min , i only get the audio

Comment: Why you don't want to use `QTimer` + slots for implementing such logic?

Comment: can't use timer  with slots, it doesn't work in a loop, i use this code in a loop

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is not as good as it looks in first sight, because it is essentially **busy wait**. You are giving processEvents at *most* 100ms. Which means, if there are no or only a few events to process, it will return much earlier. Which means, that a big amount of CPU time is spent going through your loop. In any case, your thread never gets idle.

Now have a look at using a QTimer. The QTimer will not do busy wait like you are doing, instead the thread will pause until woken up by the OS. The guaranteed granularity of a QTimer is 10 ms, so in your example it should be good enough. Here I assume `millisecondsToWait` is significantly larger than 100, the time you allow processEvents to spend.

So a probable solution to your problem is to replace your call to `delay()` with `QTimer::singleShot()` as described with an example here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#singleShot

The code that comes after `delay()` right now (continue to the next loop) would then be performed in the slot method that you use for the timer instead. By making the process asynchronous, you allow Qt and the OS to spend the CPU on where it is needed while playing the video.

Comment: i did that but still doesn't play any image, just voice no screen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do step-by-step logic without interrupting an event loop, you may use next pattern:

```
void delay( int msec )
{
  QEventLoop loop;
  QTimer::singleShot( msec, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );
  loop.exec();
}
```

Comment: Then problem is somewhere else. Provide an SSCCE, if you need a help.